# Dart: How to Implement and install a simple HTTP server

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I have been able to run the dart-by-example http-server Hello web server. 
The websocket uses port 9223 and the http server uses 8080.

After I do a build I do not find the server side code in build/bin.

What do I do next to install everything so that I could try run ws_server.dart and connect from my browser?

My Editor organization:

```
Server
  packages
  bin
    packages
    fireimager_server.dart (server side websocket handling code)
  build
    bin
    web
  lib
    communication.dart  (common code)
  web
    index.html
    main.css
    main.dart
    WebsocketClient.dart  (client websocket code)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you follow the [package layout convention](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/package-layout.html), you `server.dart` should be in `$PROJECT/bin` and your web stuff in `$PROJECT/web`.

By running `pub build` you should get a new directory `$PROJECT/build/web`. Now you can use the following `server.dart` code to expose this build directory :

```dart
library simple_http_server;

import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http_server/http_server.dart' show VirtualDirectory;

void main() {
  final MY_HTTP_ROOT_PATH = Platform.script.resolve('../build/web').toFilePath();
  final virDir = new VirtualDirectory(MY_HTTP_ROOT_PATH)
    ..allowDirectoryListing = true;

  HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.LOOPBACK_IP_V4, 8080).then((server) {
    server.listen((request) {
      virDir.serveRequest(request);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: When I run from the editor it all works.  The server opens the HTTP port and the web socket port for listening.  The client connects and then sends JSON 'message' on the web socket.  The server side code decodes it and sends a confirmation message back which is written on the client page.